# Can I choose File or InputStream for large objects in my JPA entity?

Tags: java, jpa, entity, inputstream

I want to store a large object in my database. I am doing it in JPA way.
Entity:

```
 @Entity
 public class Book
 {

   @Id
   private String bookId;

   @Column
   private String title;

   @Column
   private byte[] pdfFile;

  //setters and getters

 }
```

Can I choose `pdfFile` field as direct `File` or `InputStream` ? If yes, What's the benefit of using it?

Comment: Did you try either of them?

Comment: I know that in DataNucleus JPA you can do File, and it streams the contents of the file *at persist* hence has the benefit of not loading into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in Entity class:

```
        @Column(name = "DATA", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100000)
        private byte[] data;

        session.beginTransaction();
        File file = new File("C:\test.png");
        byte[] imageData = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(imageData);
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageWrapper image = new ImageWrapper();
        image.setImageName("test.jpeg");
        image.setData(imageData);
        session.save(image);    //Save the data

        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

for large files to save in database.

But Its better to save the file in a location and save the location in the database.

Database storage is usually more expensive than file system storage.

Blog: [To BLOB or Not To BLOB: Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Comment: FYI I don't see Hibernate in the question, he says JPA

Comment: @NeilStockton Hibernate internally use JPA only. And looks like in question `@Entity`, `@Id` etc are used. These are of hibernate only. Thanks :)

Comment: `@Entity`,  `@Id` are JPA standards. Hibernate is just *one* implementation of JPA.